# Centering y in viewport an html table cell <td> scaled on mouseover (overflow)

Tags: html, scroll, overflow, scale, viewport

Dear Members of the community,

I have built a system of colorcharts, displayed in html tables.

Each cell  gets enlarged through a transform:scale on mouse hover, to better show the color.

However, when the cell is scaled, part of it may fall outside of viewport.

Which will require the user to scroll down or up for bringing back the overflow into view.

I suppose that it would be possible to have a functionality detecting overflow and scrolling automatically to bring the scaled cell back into viewport : How can we do that please ?

I have searched for solutions to similar problems, but I fail to put pieces of code together to make it work (a few things are advanced for my programming skills, thanks for your kind understanding and help)

The function would need to :

1. get the position into viewport of the onmouseover cell after it has been transform:scale
2. compute the y difference to vertical center into viewport
3. run the scroll by this amount

Maybe a simpler alternative would be to :

1. get the position into viewport of the onmouseover cell (independent of transform:scale)
2. compute the y difference to vertical center into viewport
3. run the scroll by this amount

but in this second case the table may move constantly and be impossible to use (transform:scale comes with a small delay to avoid ergonomic issue)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand properly, so correct me if I'm wrong, I'll try to correct myself. You want to scroll by some distance so that the selected (mouse over) cell is in the middle of the page.

I would suggest to:

1. get Y position of the cell on mouseover
   `var from_top = document.getElementById('your_cell_element').offsetTop;`
2. get height of the cell (and divide by 2 so it will be in the middle  )
   `var cell_height = document.getElementById('your_cell_element').offsetHeight/2;`
3. scroll to the right position
   `window.scrollTo(0,(from_top+cell_height));`

It might need small corrections according to your exact code, you can try to share it if this dooesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Michal. How do you link 'your_cell_element' to the generic td element in tables ? Will the script compute from_top and cell_height on scaled cells, or on cell size before transform ?

Comment: Sorry for such a late answer, maybe you'll still use it. You can have a `onmouseover=scroll_function() {...}`, and then just use '**this**' keyword: `from_top = document.getElementById(this).offsetTop`... I believe it is the height before you scale it, but then you just change the last line to `window.scrollTo(0,(from_top+(cell_height*scaleing_coefficient)));`.